# Not getting Leads through registered Webhook url

Tags: linkedin-api

We are in the process of integrating the new Lead Sync API (202307 Version) into our system and have encountered an issue regarding Lead Notification Subscriptions. We were able to successfully register our webhook url at the owner level to one of our ad accounts which receives a response with 201 code, but when we try to send a test lead, we do not receive it and there is no incoming POST request to our webhook url which is also successfully validated and registered. What could be the cause for such scenario?

Stack of the Project:
Backend - PHP Framework Laravel
Frontend - React JS

Requests are made in the backend using the file_get_contents function

We tried to get leads through the old version of API (202306) and we were able to successfully retrieve leads.

Comment: Hello, i have opened [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77103858/linkedin-lead-sync-api-webhook-leadnotifications-configured-but-webhook-is-not) with more details.