# Linkedin Lead Sync API webhook (leadNotifications) configured but webhook is not called on test lead generation?

Tags: linkedin-api, webhooks

Following those documentation :

- [webhook validation process](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/linkedin/shared/api-guide/webhook-validation?context=linkedin%2Fcontext#webhook-registration-and-validation)
- [new Lead Sync API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/lead-sync/leadsync?view=li-lms-2023-08&tabs=http)

The linkedin account used for linkedin developer portal is :

- "Account Manager" in our Linkedin Campaign Manager
- "Content Admin" in our Linkedin Company Page

Products avaible to our linkedin application:
[Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxYZZ.png)

We successfully configured a webhook with this request :

- Url : https://api.linkedin.com/rest/leadNotifications
- Headers :

  - LinkedIn-Version : 202308
  - X-Restli-Protocol-Version : 2.0.0
  - Authorization : bearer token generated by [token generator](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/tools/oauth/token-generator) on linkedin developer portal with all available scopes :

    - r_ads
    - r_marketing_leadgen_automation
    - openid
    - profile
    - r_liteprofile
    - r_events
    - r_organization_admin
    - r_ads_leadgen_automation
    - email
- Body :

```
{
    "webhook":"https://{apim}.azure-api.net/{func}/LinkedinTrigger?subscription-key={{apimSecret}}",
    "owner":{
        "sponsoredAccount": "urn:li:sponsoredAccount:{accountId}"
    },
    "associatedEntity":{
        "sponsoredCreative": "urn:li:sponsoredCreative:{creativeId}"
    },
    "leadType":"SPONSORED"
}
```

The reponse of this request :

- Status : 201
- Headers :

  - Location : /leadNotifications/{createdLeadNotificationId}

Since then we can see in our logs successfull linkedin "challenges" to our webhook through GET request with "challengeCode" every 2 hours.
But our webhook is not called with POST request when a test lead is created on our mentioned test ad.

We are expecting to receive a POST request on this configured endpoint every time a lead is created from the mentioned sponsoredCreative.

The only thing we could not do, because it is not "visible", that is mentioned on Webhook documentation is the "Webhook tab" [Webhook tab documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQYKJ.png) maybe it is obsolete ? or not ?